# Removing decimals from float variable's output in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding, decimalformat

I would like to sort banknotes and coins according to an imaginary currency using strictly float variables. My code is almost finished, I only need to remove the decimals from the output.
The output could be in **n.00** **format** or, ideally, in **n format**.
All suggestions are welcome.

Sample code:

```
package TEST;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class TEST {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  //let a be currency value, r the reminder, and n the number of banknotes and coins
  float a = scanner.nextFloat();
  float r = a%500; float n = a/500;
  //500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2 banknotes; and 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 and 0.01 coins.
  
  System.out.printf("Value of currency: %5.2f%n", a);
  System.out.printf("Number of 500 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%100; n=a/100; System.out.printf("Number of 100 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%50; n=a/50; System.out.printf("Number of 50 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%20; n=a/20; System.out.printf("Number of 20 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%10; n=a/10; System.out.printf("Number of 10 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%5; n=a/5; System.out.printf("Number of 5 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%2; n=a/2; System.out.printf("Number of 2 banknotes: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.50f; n=a/0.50f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.50 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.25f; n=a/0.25f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.25 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.10f; n=a/0.10f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.10 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.05f; n=a/0.05f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.05 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.02f; n=a/0.02f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.02 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  if (r != 0) {
      a=r; r=a%0.01f; n=a/0.01f; System.out.printf("Number of 0.01 coins: %5.2f%n" , n);
  }}}}}}}}}}}}
  }}
```

Sample output:

```
666.666
Value of currency: 666.67
Number of 500 banknotes:  1.33
Number of 100 banknotes:  1.67
Number of 50 banknotes:  1.33
Number of 20 banknotes:  0.83
Number of 10 banknotes:  1.67
Number of 5 banknotes:  1.33
Number of 2 banknotes:  0.83
Number of 0.50 coins:  3.33
Number of 0.25 coins:  0.66
Number of 0.10 coins:  1.66
Number of 0.05 coins:  1.32
Number of 0.02 coins:  0.80
Number of 0.01 coins:  1.60
```

Ideal output:

```
666.666
Value of currency: 666.67
Number of 500 banknotes:  1
Number of 100 banknotes:  1
Number of 50 banknotes:  1
Number of 20 banknotes:  0
Number of 10 banknotes:  1
Number of 5 banknotes:  1
Number of 2 banknotes:  0
Number of 0.50 coins:  3
Number of 0.25 coins:  0
Number of 0.10 coins:  1
Number of 0.05 coins:  1
Number of 0.02 coins:  0
Number of 0.01 coins:  1
```

Comment: Cast it to a long

Comment: how's `%5.0f%` ? This should be a duplicate of some sort, how to use String.format or so.

Comment: Your format specifically specifies 2 DP. So... don't specifically specify 2 DP.

Comment: Why are you using floats for these variables?

Comment: For some reason I'm required to by the exercise, khelwood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the float to an int.

```
float f = 2.65f;
int i = (int)f;
System.out.println(i);

// or
System.out.printf("%d%n", (int)f);
```

Prints

```
2
2
```